# Change Connection string in LINQ-SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I have developed a windows form application using VB.Net with data access layer using LINQ-SQL. I want to allow the database to be configured from the application. I have created a form for input and save the input details in an XML file.

I need to know how to configure the LINQ to start using the new configured database on startup. I have read in one of the threads here about dynamic allocating the connection string with the following solution to include in every file where the data context is instantiated.

```
MyDataClassesDataContext db = new MyDataClassesDataContext(dynamicConnString);


protected void LinqDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, LinqDataSourceContextEventArgs e)
{
    e.ObjectInstance = new MyDataClassesDataContext (dynamicConnString);
}
```

Would this work for my scenario? In what format the connection string needs to be and how to include the password and location of database server?

Also one more question. I believe the LINQ takes care of freeing up the resources when the DataContext is destroyed. So I don’t need to worry about freeing up resources when the application exists completely (using `Application.Exit()`). Just want to confirm if this is true.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string needs to be in the correct format for ADO.Net.  If you have doubts, see
[this link](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for examples.